# Returning React Component on Cell Click in AG Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I need to render a react Component when a specific Cell is Clicked. I need help in 2 queries:
a. How to enable onCellClick only for "Comments" Column.
b. Why InDesignSiteResponse React component is not rendering on click, even I am not getting any console message as well, defined in that file.

Below are the code and screenshots attached:

Code - `{ headerName: 'Comments', field: 'remarks', valueGetter: (() => {return "Comments..."})},`

Ag-grid-definition: `<div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 600, width: 1845}}> <AgGridReact rowData={data} columnDefs={columns} onCellClicked={getComments}></AgGridReact> </div>`

getComments Function:
`const getComments = (params) => { console.log("comments", params) setShowComments(true); return (<InDesignSiteResponse stateChanger = {setShowComments} data = { params.data } />) }`

1. Actual Behavior:
   [image]

Expected Behaviour:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To activate onCellClicked event only for one column, you should do the following

```
{ 
  field: 'remarks', 
  headerName: 'Comments',      
  onCellClicked: (params) => {
    console.log('comments', params) 
    setShowComments(true);
  },
  valueGetter: (() => {return "Comments..."})}
},
```

Do not forget to remove onCellClicked from AgGridReact component.

To show comments on your modal, why don't you just use another state variable for comments and show it?

```
onCellClicked: (params) => {
  console.log('comments', params) 

  setRemarks(params.data)

  setShowComments(true)
},
```

```
<InDesignSiteResponse 
  stateChanger={setShowComments} 
  data={remarks} 
/>
```